# PHP, MySQL query executed but table not updated

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to insert some data to my DB when the page loads.

What I currently have:

```
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "xxx";
    $password = "xxx";
    $link = @mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password);
    mysql_select_db("download_time", $link);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO timestamp (id, time) VALUES ('1', 'testing');";
    mysql_query($sql, $link);
    mysql_close($link);
```

The script runs just fine and returns no errors anywhere, I've triple checked the connection and that's fine too. Running `INSERT INTO timestamp (id, time) VALUES ('1', 'testing');` through webmin I'm able to get data to be inserted just fine.

DB Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `timestamp` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `time` varchar(246) DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: _"The script runs just fine and returns no errors anywhere"_ How can you be so sure? Have you got `display_errors` turned on, and `error_reporting` set to `E_STRICT|E_ALL`? Even so, if you use the _error supressing operator of **death**: `@`_ in `@mysql_connect`, you're not helping yourself: using a deprecated extension, and hushing up any errors... that's just bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see some things that are wrong:

1) You're using mysql_* API

2) You're setting a primary key in the schema creation but you're giving a default of '1', that's wrong, a Primary Key doesn't have a default beause they're Auto Increment, you cannot have Two Identical Primary keys.

Change your schema creation to this:

```
CREATE TABLE `timestamp` (
  `id` int(10) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `time` varchar(246) DEFAULT '1'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

And the query to this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO timestamp (id, time) VALUES (null, 'testing');";
```

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe it what that simple! And sadly, yes. Not my choice to use this API :(
Quick question, how would I update the row instead of adding a new row?
I tried `UPDATE timestamp SET time='$t' WHERE id=1` but with no success?

Comment: @JoneDoes: There's no choice about it: `mysql_*` is ***deprecated***, and will be removed. Use `mysqli` (with `i` for _improved_), or `PDO`

Comment: I'm glad I helped, don't forget to mark the answer when you're able. And about the UPDATE query, I don't see why it shouldn't work

Answer (score 0):

`insert into timestamp (time) values ('testing')` leave id in MySQL hands

Comment: While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how and why this code is different from the code in the question, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.